# Finite Element Analysis: Non-singular Non-coercive matrix

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I read in a finite element book (Mixed Finite Element Methods by Boffi, Brezzi and Fortin) that "... there are zillions of non-singular matrices that are not coercive."

My experience with finite element discretization has been that a singular matrix comes from a problem that is not coercive.

What would be typical examples in finite element analysis where the resulting matrix is non-singular, but still non-coercive?

Comment: finite element on 1D laplacian operator minus 2 times identity. This is never coercive, but when $n$ is odd (or even, don't remember) the matrix is not singular

Answer (score 0):

@Exodd, I do not think it is true that $\nabla^2 - 2$ is non-coercive.

Here is a solution of $(\nabla^2-2)u  = -1$ on $[0,1]$ interval with Dirichlet BC $u(0 )=u(1) = 0$

[image]

The eigen-values of the matrix is:

1. 11 DOF

   [-39.25849329 -36.89944652 -33.18064216 -28.40335534 -22.95461289
    -17.27583843 -11.82709     -7.04978588  -3.33092781  -0.97157384
     -0.18156719]
2. 12 DOF

   [-43.31252493 -41.11926201 -37.63028448 -33.08336028 -27.78835457
    -22.10611283 -16.42386964 -11.12885865  -6.58192098  -3.09290272
     -0.89940904  -0.1664732 ]

code using FEniCS:

```
from dolfin import *
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
# global parameters
parameters ["form_compiler"]["cpp_optimize"] = True

# number of grids for mesh
P = 1 
mesh = UnitIntervalMesh(10)  # 10 for 11 DOF or 11 for 12 DOF
# mesh = Mesh("/home/fenics/demo/python/documented/dolfin_fine.xml.gz")
#sub_domains = MeshFunction("size_t", mesh, "/home/fenics/demo/python/documented/dolfin_fine_subdomains.xml.gz")

V = FunctionSpace(mesh,'P',P)

u = TrialFunction ( V )
v = TestFunction ( V )

a = -inner ( grad ( u ) , grad ( v ) )*dx - 2*u*v*dx
L = -v*dx
# Define the boundary condition
bc = DirichletBC (V , Constant(0.0) , "on_boundary")


fig,ax = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(8,6))

u = Function(V)
solve(a==L,u,bc)
pu = plot (u, title ="$\phi$")  # quiver of u field
# plot(mesh,linewidth=0.2,color='w')
# cb = fig.colorbar(pu)

# plt.savefig(save_dir + "poisson_330_deg.png")
A = assemble(a)

print(np.linalg.eigvalsh(A.array()))
```